# How to Alias a DataSet column before writing to a parquet in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with apache spark in java and what I am trying to do is filter some data, group it by a specific key and then count the number of elements for each key. At the moment I am doing this:

```
Dataset<MyBean> rawEvents = readData(spark);
        Dataset<MyBean> filtered = rawEvents.filter((FilterFunction<MyBean>) events ->
                //filter function  
            ));

KeyValueGroupedDataset<String, MyBean> grouped = filtered
                .groupByKey((MapFunction<MyBean, String>) event -> {
                   return event.getKey();
                }, Encoders.STRING());


grouped.count().write().parquet("output.parquet");
```

It fails to write because: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name "count(1)" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;`

How can I alias the count column so this does not happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grouped.count()` returns a `Dataset<Tuple2<String, Object>` in your case.

Essentially, renaming a column in the **Dataset** object will solve your problem.

You can use `withColumnRenamed` method of **Dataset** API.

```
grouped.count().withColumnRenamed("count(1)", "counts").write().parquet("output.parquet")
```

Answer (score 1):

After `grouped.count()` select all columns and also add the `alias` to count column then use write method.

Example:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;

Column[] colList =  { col("column1"), col("column2"), col("count(1)").alias("count") };
grouped.count().select(colList).write.parquet("output.parquet");
```

Comment: Assuming the columns are `value|count(1)|` could you give and example. I am new to spark.

Comment: `KeyValueGroupedDataset` does not have a `select` function.

Comment: Forgot to add ```count()``` after grouped dataset. Please see the above code and try now